# Why mail is not going?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```html
$sql="insert into landing_client_data(name,email,contact_no,company,ip,city,region,country,postal,utm_source,utm_medium,utm_term,utm_campaign,created_date) values('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['company']."','".$ip."', '".$city."', '".$region."', '".$country."', '".$postal."', '".$utm_source."', '".$utm_medium."', '".$utm_term."', '".$utm_campaign."', '".$created_date."')";
  
$res=mysql_query($sql);



//**AFTER THIS I DON'T KNOW WHETHER ITS GOING INSIDE 'if($res)' OR NOT**




if($res){
require('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'test.test6@gmail.com';            
$mail->Password = 'test@123';                        
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;



$mail->From = 'sachin@aarnasystems.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Sachin Patil CEO, Aarna Systems';                                      
$mail->setFrom('sachin@test.com', 'test');
$mail->addReplyTtesthin@test.com', 'test'); 



$mail->WordWrap = 50;                             
$mail->isHTML(true);                              

$mail->Subject = 'Enquiry: Ecommerce Website Design-';
$mail->Body    = 'Enquiry Details:<br/>
Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br/>
Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br/>
Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].'<br/>
Company: '.$_POST['company'].'<br/>';
$mail->send();

// **NoT REACHING HERE**
   
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = '/portfolio_ln/thank-you.php';
header("Location: http://$host$extra");
exit;

}
```

Everything is fine but mails are not going to desired email id. WHY? and after sending mail it should redirect to 'thankyou.php' too, but that's not working too. Please tell what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code. This will print array reponse of mailer function. After that we need to check for `[SMTPDebug]` and `[error_count:protected]` value, if both values are **NOT** 0 then it means that there is some error OR if it's 0 then there is no error in your code. Also once check `[ErrorInfo]`, this will display error message if any.

Also check with switch value of `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'` to `'ssl'`.

```
$sql="insert into landing_client_data(name,email,contact_no,company,ip,city,region,country,postal,utm_source,utm_medium,utm_term,utm_campaign,created_date) values('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['phone']."','".$_POST['company']."','".$ip."', '".$city."', '".$region."', '".$country."', '".$postal."', '".$utm_source."', '".$utm_medium."', '".$utm_term."', '".$utm_campaign."', '".$created_date."')";

$res=mysql_query($sql);

//**AFTER THIS I DON'T KNOW WHETHER ITS GOING INSIDE 'if($res)' OR NOT**

if($res){
require('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
//SMTP class
require('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'test.test6@gmail.com';            
$mail->Password = 'test@123';                        
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = 'sachin@aarnasystems.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Sachin Patil CEO, Aarna Systems';                                      
$mail->setFrom('sachin@test.com', 'test');
$mail->addReplyTo('testhin@test.com', 'test'); 

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                             
$mail->isHTML(true);                              

$mail->Subject = 'Enquiry: Ecommerce Website Design-';
$mail->Body    = 'Enquiry Details:<br/>
Name: test<br/>
Email: test@testing.com<br/>
Phone: 00447<br/>
Company: het compnay<br/>';

print('<pre >');
print_r($mail);
print('</pre>');
exit;
//$mail->send();

// **NoT REACHING HERE**

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = '/portfolio_ln/thank-you.php';
//header("Location: http://$host$extra");
//exit;
```

Let me know if there is any confusion regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. Its working now,                  require('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php'); didn't use.